# Separating "objects" within a series to be in separate columns in Python

Tags: python

I have some data that I have managed to put into a series in Python there are 369 elements in the series, within each element, there is a further two arrays containing starting x and y co-ordinates and ending x and y co-ordinates. I am looking to restructure this series in a simple data table with 369 entries and 4 columns.

First 10 Elements of the Series is

```
0    [{'y': 52, 'x': 50}, {'y': 44, 'x': 40}]
1    [{'y': 44, 'x': 40}, {'y': 75, 'x': 33}]
2    [{'y': 75, 'x': 33}, {'y': 76, 'x': 42}]
3    [{'y': 76, 'x': 42}, {'y': 36, 'x': 28}]
4    [{'y': 36, 'x': 28}, {'y': 12, 'x': 34}]
5    [{'y': 12, 'x': 34}, {'y': 30, 'x': 32}]
6    [{'y': 30, 'x': 32}, {'y': 70, 'x': 30}]
7    [{'y': 70, 'x': 30}, {'y': 35, 'x': 28}]
8    [{'y': 35, 'x': 28}, {'y': 23, 'x': 33}]
9    [{'y': 83, 'x': 46}, {'y': 87, 'x': 48}]
Name: list, dtype: object
```

By Using this, I can access the first element within that series, but ideally I want to be able to access each individual 'y' and 'x' value within these elements

```
passinglocations[1]


[{'y': 44, 'x': 40}, {'y': 75, 'x': 33}]
```

I cannot seem to find any further information in which I understand to get this in the usable form I want it

Any Insights?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you expect the transformed data to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your four columns are your y, x, y, x values, this should work:

```py
passinglocations = [
    [{'y': 44, 'x': 40}, {'y': 75, 'x': 33}],
    [{'y': 23, 'x': 15}, {'y': 25, 'x': 37}]
]

def transform(passinglocations):
    return [(loc[0]['y'], loc[0]['x'], loc[1]['y'], loc[1]['x']) for loc in passinglocations]

print(transform(passinglocations))
```

**output:**

```
[(44, 40, 75, 33), (23, 15, 25, 37)]
```